# Enable macros in Workbook Open Event

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to remove "Enable macros" and all others events of security warnings on workbook open event because when i run a powershell to open the workbook,the Workbook Open Event freeze?i find:

Application.AutomationSecurity=msoAutomationSecurityLow

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would defeat the entire purpose of those security warnings.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping really appreciate your opinion but an i have write a powershell to open the file but the code on  Workbook open event does not work and i m trying to find the mistake.

Comment: Did you try that?  Did it work, or not?

Comment: @Tim Williams unfortunately  the code still freeze after msoAutomationSecurityLow.

Comment: Do you *want* the workbook open event to run, or not?

Comment: @Tim Williams i want the code to run when the workbook open, but when the workbook open the via powershell script the workbook ask me to enable macros and the code on workbook open event freeze.

Comment: Might help to post your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You can "Trust" the document in Excel. It's a setting available from Options.

Here is a link with more information on how to do this:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/trusted-documents-cf872bd8-47ec-4c02-baa5-1fdba1a11b53

Here is a relevant snippet from the article:

*Trusted documents are files that have active content (macros, ActiveX controls, data connections, and so on) and open without the Message Bar after you enable the active content in them. For a trusted document, there is no prompt when you open the file, even if new active content was added, or changes that you make to the existing active content. However, the prompt appears if the file was moved since you last trusted the file. After a document is trusted, it does not open in Protected View. Therefore, you should trust documents only if you trust the source of the file.*